# selecting inner html dom element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how can I select the input element in something like this:

```
<div id="myDiv>
<input id="inp" />
<p>Hello</p>

</div>
```

When I select myDiv, I get that innerHtml is a string of input and paragraph elements. Is it possible to select just my input element ?

```
innerHTML: "    <input id="myDiv"/> <p>Hello</p> "
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) property,

```
$('#inp')[0].outerHTML //<input id="myDiv"/>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9U6qh/)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to select the input directly:

```
$('#myDiv > input');
```

If, for some reason, you need go through the selection containing `myDiv`, use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to select a descendent of the current selection:

```
var selection = $('#myDiv');
selection.find('input');
```

If you need to access the DOM element rather than the jQuery selection, use subscript syntax or [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$('#myDiv > input')[0];
$('#myDiv > input').get(0);
```